# Usage of "слушать" and "слышать"

Tags: выбор-слова

I'm still confused about these two verbs. Can someone lay out the differences between them and when to use each? So far all I've been able to gather is that **слушать** means *to listen* whereas **слышать** means *to hear*, but I haven't found any examples to sort of help me distinguish their usage.

Comment: hi, the difference is similar to that between their English equivalents, **to listen** is to percieve sound willfully, voluntary whereas **to hear** is to percieve it passively, involuntarily, did you try Google to search for texts where they appear?

Comment: i guess they differ like the German zu hören and anzuhören

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You understand the difference correctly. Слушать is to listen, слышать is to hear.

> Я слушаю музыку. I am listening to music. Я слышу музыку. I hear some music.

The first is a process. The second is a result.

> Ты меня слышишь?Do you hear me? Ты меня слушаешь? Are you listening to me?